# Connecting to a Plex ERP Database from Power Pivot in MS Excel using an ODBC connection

Tags: odbc, powerbi, powerpivot, powerquery, ms-query

Below is the error message:

```
DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [42S02] [Plex][ODBC ODBC Report Data Source 
driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Base table:". not found.[10129]
Details:
DataSourceKind=Odbc
DataSourcePath=dsn=Plex ODBC Connection
OdbcErrors=Table
```

***Hello, below is a post I spent a long time putting together, but cannot post the relevant images to demonstrate my issue.  I'm new here and do not have the necessary reputation points to post images.  Please help me get to 10 reputation so I can fill out the framework below with the relevant screen snips.  Thanks!***

I'll apologize from the start for being a novice.  I'm in the process of self teaching myself SQL, VBA, DAX and M.  I'm pretty good at figuring things out on a trial and error basis, but sometimes I flat out lack the necessary technical background.  This is one of those times.  Thanks in advance for your time and patience.  In return, I'll provide as much detail and background information as I can on the issue.

The company I works for uses a cloud based ERP system (https://www.plex.com/).  I want to use the ODBC to retrieve data from Plex Report Server.  I've been able to successfully connect to Plex, but I can't get Power Query to show me a preview of the tables.  That's a big issue, because I'm not familiar with the database and there are 6k+ tables for me to choose from.

I believe this is the relevant information to provide from the Plex ODBC Wiki:

- A proprietary driver is supplied by Plex to establish the connection and transmit queries. At this time the Plex ODBC driver ONLY supports secure (SSL) connections.
- The ODBC interface accepts queries that adhere to the ANSI SQL92 construct.  This is somewhat different than Microsoft's T-SQL.
- Although there is a row limit on the results returned from the ODBC server, these results are not pared until they are retrieved from the Report database.  This means long-running queries may never return any results for the ODBC server to limit.

If I connect using the method below...

(image)

...then I get this result which is desirable table preview.

(image)

However, as I stated above there are 6k+ tables so I'd like be able to use the connection to scroll through the tables and see a preview of whatever table I select.

This is how I'd normally do that...

(image)

...and this is also a desirable result, because it is showing me all of the tables.

(image)

However, when I select a table for preview this error is my problem that I can't solve.  Note this is the same table I was previously able to preview using the SELECT statement.

If I backup and select the connection itself...

(image)

...then I get this result in the Query Editor.

(image)

I'm really not sure if there is a way around this error.  My best guess is that I'm receiving the error, because the ODBC connection is a connection to just a database of the available tables; therefore, there are no columns or rows for me to preview without SELECTing a table.

Comment: It wouldn't let me post more than two links, because I lack 10 reputation points.

Comment: The question isn't really answerable... can you upload the images to imgur and include the link text?

Answer (score 0):

We run Plex ERP as well in some of our offices and we have been able to  successfully tied into Power BI and Excel

I am also not familiar with the tables of this ERP system and how we get around this is within the ERP system there is a table explore and I do my groundwork in there once I find the tables I would like to utilize for the reports I pull my selected tables into my application of choice and build the reports I require

I should also note that I work work within about 5 other ERP Systems and are  fairly familiar with how the systems structure their tables  - but no 2 are the same by any means